# android webview is showing error "Failed to load app. This app is not secured "

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

The app was working fine and properly before i uploaded it on the play store

playstore link :- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.NE.navfun&hl=en

but after one day the webview showed this error

the website i am trying to open is https://navfun.com

"Failed to load app. This app is unsecured "

Comment: Is this the exact message you are getting from webview?

Comment: Paste stack trace

Comment: i understood later that the webview is not giving me the error , rather the server was blocking all request from webview , i need to remove the "x-requested" header, is there any clean way to get rid of that header and make it look as all the request is coming from a mobile web browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // Add this
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                // DO NOT CALL SUPER METHOD
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: actually i found out that the error was not happening in my webview , but the server is actually blocking all request from webview , is there any sleek and clean way to remove the " x-requested  " header from all webview get requests ?